# Application to convert a sentence into a bunch of songs put together singing what you said

Tags: webapp-rec

A while ago I found a website that allowed you to enter a word, sentence, etc... and then it would generate a sound clip that used various lines from songs to essentially say out those words. It was a very interesting web app and I have had little luck finding it in Google again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I think this question is out of the scope of Webapps, the tool sounded interesting so I did some research.

Is "Let them sing it for you" the tool you're looking for?

[Looks like the original creator](http://www.erikbunger.com/html/let_them_sing.html) has stopped hosting the project:

> For unknown reasons the Swedish National Radio decided not to host the
>   project anymore in late 2011. Hopefully it will be up soon again.

There is a Chrome Extension that still lets you do this however. I will not put the link here because you should always be wary of installing extensions from untrusted authors. But if you want to investigate and give it a try, search for "Let them sing it for you" in the Chrome store under "Extensions"

Comment: Yes, this is it! Just wondering what you actually had to search to find this. My search results were not turning up anything.

Comment: I searched for `type your sentence in song lyrics` and the top hit was a Reddit thread about this tool :) - that was my ~7th try at searching...it was definitely hard to narrow it down to find a usable result

Comment: Okay, awesome! I tried out the chrome extension and it works just like the old web app I remember!